# Regex issue with a string and all numbers

Tags: ruby, regex

In Ruby, I would like to create a regular expression that matches the following:

```
building/liberty-green/6d
```

(the word `building` and some number somewhere after it)

Currently, I have `/building/` and need to add `\d` (any digit) to it, but I don't know how.

Comment: Prepare your question first, then ask us. Your question is not clear.

Comment: If you're asking a regex question, it helps to give a list of strings that the expression needs to match - otherwise it's very hard to come up with an expression that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `/building\/[\w-]+\/\w+/`. For example:

```
irb(main):001:0> /building\/[\w-]+\/\w+/.match("building/liberty-green/6d")
=> #<MatchData "building/liberty-green/6d">
```

That expression will match any string that:

- Starts with `/building/`
- Then follows with one or more word characters or dashes (eg. `foo-bar`, `foo`, `bar-1`)
- Then follows with a `/`
- Finally ends with one or more word characters (eg. `foo`, `6d`, `12345`)

Note that `\w` includes digits.

Comment: it needs to be able to match a url such as building/liberty-green/6d